# Elm327 an app control

Tags: electronic-control-module

Is there a Android App that's used with the elm327 tool to slightly advance  timing on cars?
I know many can read it but I'm looking for the ones that slightly can raise or lower it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

While this in essence is a shopping question (and could be closed for that reason), the simple answer to your question is ... No. ELM327 devices are meant for reading what's going on with the ECU, not to write a tune to it. To change the timing (the right way) on newer electronically controlled vehicles you need to change the tune. There are ways which you could change the timing which I'd advise against, like physically changing how something mechanically behaves, but this isn't a good approach.

Also, using a wireless device to write a tune to your ECU is not a wise choice. The reason being is if it loses connection for any reason during the write, you brick the ECU, meaning it will no longer work. When writing a tune, you need to ensure you have a proper stable connection along with plenty of power for the device which is doing the writing. If it loses connection or stops in the middle for any reason ... you now have a paper weight instead of an ECU. Any Bluetooth or Wi-Fi enabled device can also receive electronic interference from other devices, which could interrupt the signal between your originating device and the ELM327, which would brick the ECU. If I haven't stated it already, interruption while writing a tune is *a very bad thing*.

Answer (score 0):

I did it manually .I was able to monitor rpm  on ELM , i  adjusted dizzy/ timing to  720 rpm though 700 is the normal idle .jumpered the service wire also.
Running good now..